# How would i implement JavaScript into this

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey Everyone is i have an social bar that i made with CSS and html and i was wondering instead of making it show Quickly how would i implement JavaScript so i can pick the speed that the image slides up  This is my code

**CSS**

```
 .sharing-cl {

     overflow:hidden;

     margin:0;

     padding:0;

     list-style:none;

 }

 .sharing-cl a {

     overflow:hidden;

     width:75px;

     height:30px;

     float:left;

     margin-right:5px;

     text-indent:-200px;

     background:url("http://theirondoor.x10.bz/V2/images/share-sprite.png") no-repeat;

 }

 a.sh-Youtube {

     background-position:-214px -40px;

 }

 a.sh-Twitter {

     background-position:-61px -40px;

 }

 a.sh-Rss {

     background-position:-143px -40px;

 }

 a.sh-Facebook {

     background-position:20px -40px;

 }

 a.sh-Youtube:hover {

     background-position:-214px 1px;

 }

 a.sh-Twitter:hover {

     background-position:-61px 1px;

 }

 a.sh-Rss:hover {

     background-position:-143px 1px;

 }

 a.sh-Facebook:hover {

     background-position:20px 1px;

 }

 #text {

     margin-top:3em;

     font-weight:bold;

     font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;

 }

 #text a {

     text-indent:0;

     height:auto;

     text-align:center;

     font-size:11px;

     padding-top:35px;

     color:#999;

     text-decoration:none;

 }
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="sharing-cl" id="text">
    <li></li>
    <li><a class="sh-Facebook" href="">Facebook</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="sh-Twitter" href="">Twitter</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="sh-Rss" href="">  Rss Feed</a>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li><a class="sh-Youtube" href="">Youtube</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the  jsFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Kf5CS/

Comment: You should probably use CSS animations instead of javascript. Use: `transition: background-position 1s;` with the relevant vendor prefixes.

Comment: Why do you want to use JavaScript? You could do that with CSS animations/transitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 a.sh-Facebook {

     background-position:20px -40px;
-webkit-transition-property: background;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;

 }
```

So, as you can see, you should use "transition" property to let you icons move, you can setany duration you want in "duration" property